# Importing the numpy c-extensions failed in MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, numpy

**Importing the numpy c-extensions failed**
I am trying to use numpy in terminal, when i imported it it returned an error.But whe I import numpy in pytharm Python Console,it worked well.I have python 2.7.10 and 3.7.5,python 3.7.5 was used in pytharm. I uninstalled numpy on all versions of python and reinstalled it on python 3.7.5 only, but it returned the same error.  I reinstall packages via the command line by entering:

```
 python3 -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

but it returned the same error too.I guess it's a multi-environment problem.
Tried uninstall and install numpy and setuptools like this:

```
pip uninstall -y numpy

pip uninstall -y setuptools

pip install setuptools

pip install numpy
```

but it returned the same error too.

My python3 pip list:

```
absl-py              0.9.0   
aiodns               2.0.0   
aiohttp              3.5.4   
appnope              0.1.0   
astor                0.8.1   
async-timeout        3.0.1   
attrs                19.1.0  
backcall             0.1.0   
beautifulsoup4       4.5.3   
bleach               3.1.0   
browsermob-proxy     0.8.0   
bs4                  0.0.1   
cchardet             2.1.4   
certifi              2019.3.9
cffi                 1.12.3  
chardet              3.0.4   
cssselect            1.0.3   
cycler               0.10.0  
decorator            4.4.1   
defusedxml           0.6.0   
entrypoints          0.3     
fake-useragent       0.1.11  
gast                 0.3.2   
google-pasta         0.1.8   
grpcio               1.26.0  
h5py                 2.10.0  
idna                 2.6     
importlib-metadata   1.3.0   
ipykernel            5.1.3   
ipython              5.4.1   
ipython-genutils     0.2.0   
ipywidgets           7.5.1   
jedi                 0.15.2  
Jinja2               2.10.3  
joblib               0.14.1  
jsonschema           3.2.0   
jupyter              1.0.0   
jupyter-client       5.3.4   
jupyter-console      5.2.0   
jupyter-core         4.6.1   
Keras                2.2.4   
Keras-Applications   1.0.8   
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0   
kiwisolver           1.1.0   
lxml                 4.3.3   
Markdown             3.1.1   
MarkupSafe           1.1.1   
matplotlib           3.1.2   
mistune              0.8.4   
more-itertools       8.0.2   
mpmath               1.1.0   
multidict            4.5.2   
nbconvert            5.6.1   
nbformat             4.4.0   
nose                 1.3.7   
notebook             6.0.2   
ntplib               0.3.3   
numpy                1.17.4  
opencv-python        4.1.2.30
pandas               0.25.3  
pandocfilters        1.4.2   
parso                0.5.2   
pexpect              4.7.0   
pickleshare          0.7.5   
Pillow               6.2.1   
pip                  19.3.1  
prometheus-client    0.7.1   
prompt-toolkit       1.0.18  
protobuf             3.11.2  
ptyprocess           0.6.0   
pycares              3.0.0   
pycparser            2.19    
pycrypto             2.6.1   
Pygments             2.5.2   
PyMySQL              0.9.3   
pyparsing            2.4.5   
pyquery              1.4.0   
pyrsistent           0.15.6  
python-dateutil      2.8.1   
pytz                 2019.3  
PyYAML               5.2     
pyzmq                18.1.1  
qtconsole            4.6.0   
redis                3.3.11  
requests             2.18.4  
scikit-learn         0.22    
scipy                1.4.1   
selenium             3.11.0  
Send2Trash           1.5.0   
setuptools           42.0.2  
simplegeneric        0.8.1   
six                  1.13.0  
sklearn              0.0     
soupsieve            1.9.1   
splinter             0.13.0  
sympy                1.5     
tensorboard          1.14.0  
tensorflow           1.14.0  
tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0  
termcolor            1.1.0   
terminado            0.8.3   
testpath             0.4.4   
tornado              6.0.3   
traitlets            4.3.3   
urllib3              1.22    
wcwidth              0.1.7   
webencodings         0.5.1   
Werkzeug             0.16.0  
wheel                0.33.6  
widgetsnbextension   3.5.1   
wrapcache            1.0.8   
wrapt                1.11.1  
xvfbwrapper          0.2.9   
yarl                 1.3.0   
zipp                 0.6.0
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Reproducing code example:**

```
import numpy
```

**Error message:**

> Blockquote
>   Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  1 2019, 02:16:32)  [Clang 11.0.0
>   (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import numpy Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 17, in 
> > > >             from . import multiarray   File "/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py",
> > > >         line 14, in 
> > > >             from . import overrides   File "/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py",
> > > >         line 7, in 
> > > >             from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so,
> > > >         2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3   Referenced from:
> > > >         /Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
> > > >         /Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py",
>   line 142, in 
>       from . import core   File "/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
>   - Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
>   - If you have already done that, then:
>     1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7",
>        and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
>        interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.
>     2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
>        https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
>        - how you installed Python
>        - how you installed numpy
>        - your operating system
>        - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
>        - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
>
> - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`   (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
>
> Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
>   an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
>
> Original error was:
>   dlopen(/Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: ___addtf3   Referenced from:
>   /Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
>   /Users/chuck/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/../.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue like this:

```
bogon:bin chuck$ brew unlink python3
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5... 0 symlinks removed

bogon:bin chuck$ brew link python3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/easy_install-3.7
Target /usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.7
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.7'
To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python
To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python

bogon:bin chuck$ brew link --overwrite python3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5... 24 symlinks created
```